# Как использовать слэши в коммандах psycopg2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

Суть:
Нужно поработать скриптом над выводом Postgres после выполнения команды \dRs. Через psql команда выполняется, вывод нормальный. А вот когда хочу через psycopg2 то же самое повторить, то не получается:

Input:

```
cursor.execute('\dRs')
```

Output:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "\"
```

P.S. r"\dRs", так же не работает...

Comment: Посмотрел про команду в https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/10/app-psql А разве это не при интерактивном общении с базой? В `execute` нужно передавать SQL запрос, а команда в вашем вопросе это другое

Comment: Хорошо, а как тогда выполнить эту команду, используя psycopg2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужно из скрипта выполнять интерактивную команду, нужно будет запустить программу для базы (`psql`) и ввести в нее команду `\dRs`, после считать результат

[Пример взят из ответа с enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53087565/5909792):

```
import sys
import subprocess

import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', dbname='test', user='postgres')
conn.autocommit = True

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('create table my_table(id int primary key, str text)')

res = subprocess.run('psql -c "\d+ my_table" test postgres', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(res.stdout.decode(sys.stdout.encoding))
```

Результат:

```
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id     | integer |           | not null |         | plain    |              | 
 str    | text    |           |          |         | extended |              | 
Indexes:
    "my_table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```